# Trouble using if statement in bash script to check if package installed

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I am new to Bash scripting and having difficulty writing this function that I want to use to check if a package is installed or not. My code is:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function is_installed() {
    if [ -n $(dpkg -l | awk "/^ii  $1/")]; then
        echo 1;
    fi
    echo 0;
}

if is_installed "coreutils"; then
    echo "coreutils installed";
else
    echo "coreutils not installed";
fi
```

Instead of the expected behavior of printing only "coreutils installed", this prints "0", then "1", then "coreutils installed" into the terminal. I think I am not understanding something about Bash syntax here, particularly with complicated if-thens. Any help?

Comment: `if dpkg --verify coreutils 2>/dev/null; then echo "correctly installed"; else echo "not correctly installed"; fi`?

Comment: The `echo 0` is very unlikely to fail, so `is_installed "coreutils"` will almost always return successfully and the main script will `echo "coreutils installed"` regardless of the output of `dpkg -l`

Comment: In addition to the `echo` vs `return` problem, you also have incorrect spacing and quoting in the `if` statement. Specifically, you need double-quotes around the `$( )` bit, and a space between that and the `]`. I recommend using [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) to find these common mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if command` checks the exit status of `command` and not its output. Therefore you should change `echo x` (*= output x*) to `return x` (*= exit function with status code x*).

```
is_installed() {
    if [ -n "$(dpkg -l | awk "/^ii  $1/")" ]; then
        return 1;
    fi
    return 0;
}
```

This can also be shortened to

```
is_installed() {
    [ -z "$(dpkg -l | awk "/^ii  $1/")" ]
}
```

For further improvements of the actual check, see [Cyrus' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65647287/trouble-using-if-statement-in-bash-script-to-check-if-package-installed/65647357#comment116067344_65647287):

```
is_installed() {
     dpkg --verify "$1" 2>/dev/null
}
```